# RViz & amcl - fixed_frame mismatch for initialpose

Tags: navigation, rviz, ubuntu, ubuntu-trusty, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a multi-robot system (two robots, for now) in which each is pushed into a namespace (`/robot1` and `/robot2`) using [Jakub's answer on how to setup a mulit-robot system](https://answers.ros.org/question/41433/multiple-robots-simulation-and-navigation/?answer=41434#post-id-41434) (which I updated for Indigo and use the Pioneer 3dx instead of the turtlebot).

Most everything is working fine except for when I try to set the inital pose manually for `amcl` using `RViz`. I set the `fixed_frame` to be `/map` which is what both robots (and `amcl` for both) are using. `amcl` is subscribed to `/robot1/initialpose` for one robot and `/robot2/initialpose` for the other so, using the `Tool Properties` in `RViz` I set the topic for the `2D Pose Estimate` to be `/robot1/initialpose`.

When I attempt to set the pose from `RViz` I get the following warning from `amcl`:

```
Ignoring initial pose in frame "map"; initial poses must be in the global frame, "/map"
```

This warning comes up despite the fact that I set `/map` as the `fixed_frame` in `RViz`. When I echo the topic and set the pose, I get this:

```
header: 
  seq: 0
  stamp: 
    secs: 282
    nsecs: 751000000
  frame_id: map
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: 25.1116027832
      y: 51.6672058105
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: -0.827484384125
      w: 0.561488730099
  covariance: [0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.06853891945200942]
```

which results in the above error (note the `frame_id` of `map` without a `/`). However, if I publish the same message myself but with a `frame_id` of `/map` instead of `map` I get the following output from `amcl`:

```
Setting pose (408.542000): 25.112 51.667 -1.949
```

How do I change the`fixed_frame` for the `initialpose` or am I missing sometheing here? Is it a bug?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268436/rviz-&-amcl---fixed_frame-mismatch-for-initialpose/) by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on ROS Answers with karma: 6155 on 2017-08-09

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem seems to be, that RVIZ removes any leading '/' from the fixed_frame (you actually see it in the GUI), which doesn't look right to me. Can you set amcl to use the "map" frame without the leading '/'?

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2017-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-10**:
Your solution worked. I find some parts of the namespacing to be a little confusing and this is one area where that showed. I thought that I had to have the `/` prepended to the beginning of the `frame_id`. Looks like I was wrong.

**Comment by [nightwish](https://answers.ros.org/users/35698/nightwish/) on 2018-06-19**:
Hi, I followed the tutorial too and got the same problem. I set amcl to use the "map" frame without the leading '/' as the suggestion of @Sebastian and there was no error or warning message in output.
However, the robot's position in rviz remain unchanged.
Could you help me deal with this?
Thanks!

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-06-19**:
@nightwish please create a new question and reference this question.